# My django tag doesn't apply and it's displayed on the site page

Tags: html, django

I have a problem, I would like to apply a `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` tag on my template to hide a button. But when I add the tag, it display the `if` statement on the page.

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load base_tags %}
{% load guardian_tags %}

{% user_can_add_resource_base as add_tag %}
{% verbatim %}

<div class="row resourcebase-snippet">
  <div ng-if="results.length == 0" ng-cloak>
    <div><h3>No content created yet.</h3></div>
  </div>
  <article ng-repeat="item in results" resource_id="{{ item.id }}" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
    <div class="col-lg-12 item-container">
      <div class="col-lg-12 profile-avatar">
        <div class="col-lg-4 item-thumb">
          <a href="{{ item.detail_url }}">
            <img ng-src="{{ item.thumbnail_url }}" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 item-details">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10">
              <p class="item-meta">
                  <span class="item-category">{{ item.category__gn_description }}</span><br>
                  <span class="item-category" ng-if="item.group"><a href="/groups/group/{{ item.group }}/activity/"><i class="fa fa-group" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i>{{ item.group_name }}</a><br></span>
                  <span class="item-category" ng-if="item.has_time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right: 8px;"></i>Temporal Serie<br></span>
              </p>
              <h4>
                  <i ng-if="item.store_type == 'remoteStore'" title="Remote Service" class="fa fa-external-link fa-1" style="vertical-align:  middle;padding-right: 10px;"></i>
                  <i ng-if="item.store_type == 'dataStore'" title="Vector Data" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-1" style="vertical-align:  middle;padding-right: 10px;"></i>
                  <i ng-if="item.store_type == 'coverageStore'" title="Raster Data" class="fa fa-picture-o fa-1" style="vertical-align:  middle;padding-right: 10px;"></i>
                  <i ng-if="item.store_type == 'dataset'" title="File/Dataset" class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-1" style="vertical-align:  middle;padding-right: 10px;"></i>
                  <i ng-if="item.store_type == 'map'" title="Map" class="fa fa-map-o fa-1" style="vertical-align:  middle;padding-right: 10px;"></i>
                  <a href="{{ item.detail_url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
             {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <h4>
                <button
                  class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right"
                  ng-if="cart"
                  ng-click="cart.toggleItem(item)"
                  data-toggle="tooltip"
                  data-placement="bottom"
                  title="Select"><i ng-class="cart.getFaClass(item.id)" class="fa fa-lg"></i></button>
             </h4>
             {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
          <em ng-if="item.store_type == 'remoteStore'">
            {% endverbatim %}
            <span ng-if="item.online == true"><i class="fa fa-power-off text-success"></i> {% trans "Service is" %} {% trans "online" %}</span>
            <span ng-if="item.online == false"><i class="fa fa-power-off text-danger"></i> {% trans "Service is" %} {% trans "offline" %}</span>
            {% verbatim %}
          </em>
          <div class="alert alert-warning" ng-if="item.is_approved == false">PENDING APPROVAL</div>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="item.is_approved == true && item.is_published == false">UNPUBLISHED</div>
          <p class="abstract">{{ item.abstract | limitTo: 300 }}{{ item.abstract.length  > 300 ? '...' : ''}}</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 item-items">
              <ul class="list-inline">
                <li><a href="/people/profile/{{ item.owner__username }}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>{{ item.owner_name }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ item.detail_url }}#info"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>{{ item.date|date:'d MMM y' }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ item.detail_url }}"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>{{ item.popular_count }}</a></li>
                    <li><a ng-if="item.detail_url.indexOf('/layers/') > -1" href="{% endverbatim %}{% url "new_map" %}?layer={% verbatim %}{{ item.detail_url.substring(8) }}">
                    {% endverbatim %}
                            {% user_can_add_resource_base as add_tag %}
                            {% if add_tag %}
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>{% trans "Create a Map" %}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% verbatim %}
                    </li>
                <li><a ng-if="item.detail_url.indexOf('/maps/') > -1" href="/maps/{{item.id}}/view"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>View Map</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
{% endverbatim %}
```

Comment: post the full html file. this is not the place from where the if is displayed

Comment: Because you're using the `verbatim` tag. That's literally what it does.